# Magento Adress fields in backend not displaying + Access Denied

Tags: magento, magento2

I can do anything with my magento backend, but I do have one problem with the customer details. All orders don't show the customer address but just a "*"

I tried to setup:upgrade magento and then compile and deploy the static content without any luck.

I also created a new user role with all permissions and logged in to that account, but I still can't see the customer address.

Below picture:
[Adress fields *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkZxg.png)

[When clicked on edit address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBxyV.png)

Does anyone have any suggestion on what to do?

Comment: I am wondering the same. Administrators surely should have access to _everything_ by default, I thought? I haven't found a way to disable this obfuscation for Administrators. I cannot even edit any addresses from orders - Magento 2.4.3 will just show "Access denied" in the back end.